# How to set Appium tests (WDIO-Mocha tests) pass % tolerance on BitRise Test Jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, appium, webdriver-io, bitrise

How to set Appium tests (WDIO-Mocha tests) pass % tolerance on BitRise Test Jobs

Hi,
We are running UI Test Suite on BitRise CI/CD.
The test suite itself is built on ReactNative/Jest codebase.
And WDIO-Mocha runner is used for running the tests.

**Exports.conf**

```
exports.config = {
specs: [
    './<my directory>/**/*.<testName>.js'
],
exclude: [],
maxInstances: 1,
capabilities: [],
sync: true,
logLevel: 'verbose',
coloredLogs: true,
deprecationWarnings: true,
bail: 0,
screenshotPath: './errorShots/',
waitforTimeout: 5000,
connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
connectionRetryCount: 3,
baseUrl: '',
framework: 'mocha',
mochaOpts: {
    ui: 'bdd',
    timeout: 90000,
    logLevel: 'info',
    logOutput: './wdio.log'
},
reporters: ['dot', 'allure'],

before() {
    require('@babel/register');

    global.expect = jestMatchers;
}
```

};

How to set pass % tolerance viz- 98% or 90% etc

[For Example- On CI/CDs like - Jenkins we can achieve this using Hidden parameter mechanism or on TeamCity CI/CD it comes as out of box facility]

Thanks

Comment: Can you please link to the related official Appium docs that explains what "pass % tolerance viz" is?

Comment: Appium /Selenium do not provide such functionality whereas, we're using Mocha /Jest runner to run Appium-WDIO.js tests.

Comment: That's fine, then the link to the official documentation of `"pass % tolerance viz"` that explains where/how you can set that for the tool.